# Howto apply delayed(CMS) signature to pdf document using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I need to add a cryptographic signature to a pdf document using CMS. 
Eventually, a commercial service will be used for creating the signature based on the hash from the pdf document. 
At the moment, i am trying to create such a document using self signed certificates.

I am using the ITextSharp library version 5.5.13 for this. 
I did create a simple console application which does essentially the following:

1. Create a hash and a signing prepared pdf document based on an existing pdf document.
2. Create a SHA256 signature from the hash using a X509Certificate
3. Add the signature to the pdf document created in step 1

The following already works:

1. Create the prepared pdf document
2. Create the hash value
3. Create the SHA256 signature

But i am unable to apply the signature to the prepared pdf document.

I am loading the prepared pdf, but the SignatureAppearance is null. 
I need to add a cryptographic signature to a pdf document using CMS. 
Eventually, a commercial service will be used for creating the signature based on the hash from the pdf document. 
At the moment, i am trying to create such a document using self signed certificates.

But i am unable to apply the signature to the prepared pdf document. 
I am loading the prepared pdf, but the SignatureAppearance is null.

```
public void AddSignatureToPreparedPdf(byte[] signature)
{
    //read the prepared pdf document (This document is ready to be signed)
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PreparedForSigningDocumentPath))
    {
        //The filestream into which the newly signed document must be written.
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(SignedPdfPath))
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileStream, '\0');

            var appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            var pdfDictionary = new PdfDictionary();
            var paddedSignature = new byte[SIGNATURE_ESTIMATED_SIZE];

            Array.Copy(signature, 0, paddedSignature, 0, signature.Length);
            pdfDictionary.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSignature).SetHexWriting(true));

            Dictionary<PdfName, int> exclusionSizes = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
            exclusionSizes.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, (SIGNATURE_ESTIMATED_SIZE * 2) + 2);

            appearance.PreClose(exclusionSizes);
            appearance.Close(pdfDictionary);
        }
    }
}
```

The sample below contains a single class with all required code to run.. 
The following tasks are required in order to run it: Change the paths to the pdf files and create a self signed certificate and change the path and password in the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;

namespace MobileIDTestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string unsignedDocumentPath = @"C:\temp\UnsignedDocument.pdf";
            string signedDocumentPath = @"C:\temp\SignedDocument.pdf";
            string preparedForSigningDocumentPath = @"C:\temp\SigningPreparedDocument.pdf";

            ITextTest iTextTest = new ITextTest(unsignedDocumentPath, signedDocumentPath, preparedForSigningDocumentPath);

            //Create the new sign-ready pdf, and returns the hash value
            iTextTest.PreparePdfForSigning();

            //Sign the hash value
            // >> This is eventually done by a dedicated service <<
            var signature = iTextTest.SignHash();

            //Add the newly created signature to the previously created document
            iTextTest.AddSignatureToPreparedPdf(signature);
        }
    }


    public class ITextTest
    {
        //Space allocated in the new pdf document for the signature
        private int SIGNATURE_ESTIMATED_SIZE = 8192;

        //Path to my test certificate (including the private key). Needs to be replaced with certificate from cert store
        private string CertificatePath = @"C:\project\tech\mobileidtest\ws16.pfx";
        private string CertificatePassword = "xxx";

        private readonly string UnsignedPdfPath;
        private readonly string PreparedForSigningDocumentPath;
        private readonly string SignedPdfPath;

        public string PdfHash { get; set; }

        public ITextTest(string UnsignedPdfPath, string SignedPdfPath, string preparedForSigningDocumentPath)
        {
            this.UnsignedPdfPath = UnsignedPdfPath;
            this.SignedPdfPath = SignedPdfPath;
            this.PreparedForSigningDocumentPath = preparedForSigningDocumentPath;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Prepare a pdf document for signing
        /// * Add a signature placeholder
        /// * Create a hash which will be signed later
        /// * Save the prepared pdf document
        /// </summary>
        public void PreparePdfForSigning()
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(UnsignedPdfPath))
            {
                FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(PreparedForSigningDocumentPath);
                PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;

                appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(500, 150, 400, 200), 1, "SignatureFieldName1");
                appearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
                appearance.Reason = "My signing reason";
                appearance.Location = "Somewhere";
                appearance.Contact = "Foo Bar";
                StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                buf.Append("Digitally signed by");
                buf.Append("\n");
                buf.Append("Foo Bar");
                buf.Append("\n");
                buf.Append("Date: " + appearance.SignDate);
                appearance.Layer2Text = buf.ToString();
                appearance.Acro6Layers = true;
                appearance.CertificationLevel = 0;
                PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED)
                {
                    Date = new PdfDate(appearance.SignDate),
                    Name = "Foo Bar"
                };
                dic.Reason = appearance.Reason;
                dic.Location = appearance.Location;
                dic.Contact = appearance.Contact;

                appearance.CryptoDictionary = dic;
                Dictionary<PdfName, int> exclusionSizes = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
                exclusionSizes.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, (SIGNATURE_ESTIMATED_SIZE * 2) + 2);

                IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
                MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, SIGNATURE_ESTIMATED_SIZE);

                //  appearance.PreClose(exclusionSizes); >> not sure whether this is required
                HashAlgorithm sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
                Stream s = appearance.GetRangeStream();
                int read = 0;
                byte[] buff = new byte[0x2000];
                while ((read = s.Read(buff, 0, 0x2000)) > 0)
                {
                    sha.TransformBlock(buff, 0, read, buff, 0);
                }
                sha.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, 0);

                StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(sha.Hash.Length * 2);
                foreach (byte b in sha.Hash)
                    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

                PdfHash = hex.ToString();
            }
        }




        /// <summary>
        /// Create a SHA256 signature from a given hash value
        /// It uses a self signed certificate
        /// Once this runs properly, this task will be performed by a secure signing service
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A SHA256 signature</returns>
        public byte[] SignHash()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PdfHash))
                throw new Exception("no hash available");

            byte[] hash = StringToByteArray(PdfHash);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(CertificatePath, FileMode.Open);
            Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12Store(fs, CertificatePassword.ToCharArray());
            String alias = "";
            foreach (string al in store.Aliases)
                if (store.IsKeyEntry(al) && store.GetKey(al).Key.IsPrivate)
                {
                    alias = al;
                    break;
                }
            AsymmetricKeyEntry pk = store.GetKey(alias);
            X509CertificateEntry[] chain = store.GetCertificateChain(alias);
            List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> c = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();
            foreach (X509CertificateEntry en in chain)
            {
                c.Add(en.Certificate);
            }
            PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk.Key, "SHA256");
            String hashAlgorithm = signature.GetHashAlgorithm();
            PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, c, hashAlgorithm, false);
            DateTime signingTime = DateTime.Now;
            byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
            byte[] extSignature = signature.Sign(sh);
            sgn.SetExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.GetEncryptionAlgorithm());
            return sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a byte array from a hex string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hex"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                .ToArray();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a signature to the prepared pdf document
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="signature"></param>
        public void AddSignatureToPreparedPdf(byte[] signature)
        {
            //read the prepared pdf document (This document is ready to be signed)
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PreparedForSigningDocumentPath))
            {
                //The filestream into which the newly signed document must be written.
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(SignedPdfPath))
                {
                    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileStream, '\0');

                    var appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                    var pdfDictionary = new PdfDictionary();
                    var paddedSignature = new byte[SIGNATURE_ESTIMATED_SIZE];

                    Array.Copy(signature, 0, paddedSignature, 0, signature.Length);
                    pdfDictionary.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSignature).SetHexWriting(true));

                    Dictionary<PdfName, int> exclusionSizes = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
                    exclusionSizes.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, (SIGNATURE_ESTIMATED_SIZE * 2) + 2);

                    appearance.PreClose(exclusionSizes);
                    appearance.Close(pdfDictionary);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like a mix of signing code for different versions of the iText signing API. You probably should start by reading the [Digital Signatures for PDF Documents](https://itextpdf.com/de/resources/books/digital-signatures-pdf) white paper by iText. You'll find the C# code corresponding to the Java code in the white paper [here](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5NS/repos/tutorial/browse/signatures).

Comment: You might be right. I did not find the documentation and did copy parts from different sources. I'll try to integrate according to the documentation and post an update once it's done

Comment: I was able to run sample C4_09_DeferredSigning from the IText sample git repository (https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5NS/repos/tutorial/browse/signatures/chapter4/C4_09_DeferredSigning). But this sample doesn't create a hash and use this signed hash to sign the document. As soon as i have access to the real Test Infrastructure i will update this comment

Comment: Note: The problem is that is did saved the prepared pdf as a file, and then tried to apply the signature to this newly loaded file. This seems not to be possible using IText. You need to create the signature request, get the signature and apply it without saving the pdf into a file in between.

Comment: *"You need to create the signature request, get the signature and apply it without saving the pdf into a file in between."* - That is not correct. You claim to have looked at `C4_09_DeferredSigning`, and that example *does save the PDF between a preparation step and a signing step*. You claim *"this sample doesn't create a hash and use this signed hash to sign the document"* but it does, look at  `byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, hashAlgorithm)` in `MyExternalSignatureContainer.Sign` for the hash creation and the code thereafter in that method for the signing of the hash.